# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object class

Tags: apex, exception, null-pointer

Can anyone help me in changing this query.

```
 public void ReAssignTask(List<Task> taskList){
    //Initialize variables
    String tempContainer;
    Set<Id> taskOwners = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id,Id> taskOwnerMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
    Map<Id,Id> taskParentMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
    Map<Id,String> userProfileMap = new Map<Id,String>();
    Map<Id,Id> vsrToSR = new Map<Id,Id>();
    Map<Id,Id> srToVSR = new Map<Id,Id>();

    //Get owners of the tasks
    for(Task loopTask : taskList){
        taskOwnerMap.put(loopTask.Id, loopTask.OwnerId);
        taskParentMap.put(loopTask.Id, loopTask.WhatId);
    }

    //Group tasks depending on the profile of the owners of the tasks
    for(User loopUser : [SELECT id, profile.name FROM User WHERE Id IN :taskOwnerMap.values()]){
        userProfileMap.put(loopUser.Id, loopUser.profile.name);
    }

    for(Veeva_Service_Request__c loopVSR : [SELECT Id, Service_Request_Id__c 
                                            FROM Veeva_Service_Request__c
                                            WHERE Id IN :taskParentMap.values()
                                                OR Service_Request_Id__c IN :taskParentMap.values()]){
        //Get Service Request for Veeva Service Request
        srToVSR.put(loopVSR.Service_Request_Id__c, loopVSR.Id);
        //Get Veeva Service Request for Service Requests
        vsrToSR.put(loopVSR.Id, loopVSR.Service_Request_Id__c);
    }

    //Re-assign service request tasks to its veeva service request counterpart
    for(Task loopTask : taskList){
        if(loopTask.WhatId.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName() != 'Case' && 
           loopTask.WhatId.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName() != 'Veeva_Service_Request__c' &&
           (userProfileMap.get(loopTask.OwnerId).contains('NAM') || 
            userProfileMap.get(loopTask.OwnerId).contains('LSM'))){
            loopTask.addError('A task cannot be assigned to LSM/NAM users if it is not related to a Case.');
        }
        if((userProfileMap.get(taskOwnerMap.get(loopTask.Id)).toLowerCase()).contains('nam')){
            //Assign task from service request to veeva service request
            if(srToVSR.containsKey(loopTask.whatId)){
                loopTask.Service_Request_LookUp__c = loopTask.whatId;
                loopTask.whatId = srToVSR.get(loopTask.whatId);
            }
        }else if((userProfileMap.get(taskOwnerMap.get(loopTask.Id)).toLowerCase()).contains('lsm')){
            //Assign task from service request to veeva service request
            if(srToVSR.containsKey(loopTask.whatId)){
                loopTask.Service_Request_LookUp__c = loopTask.whatId;
                loopTask.whatId = srToVSR.get(loopTask.whatId);
            }
        }else{
            //Assign task from veeva service request to service request
            if(vsrToSR.containsKey(loopTask.whatId)){
                loopTask.Veeva_Service_Request_LookUp__c = loopTask.whatId;
                loopTask.whatId = vsrToSR.get(loopTask.whatId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If `taskParentMap` is null then you would get that error.

Comment: CAn you help me to modify the code.

Comment: You have not provided enough code to see what the issue is.

Comment: It says too longs can I have your email to send my code.Ken sfdc1
trigger Task_Trigger on Task (before insert) {
    Task_TriggerHandler handler = new Task_TriggerHandler();
    //Runs on before insert only
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
        //Re-assigns tasks
        handler.ReAssignTask(Trigger.new);
    }
}This is the trigger calling the class but I cant past the class as it is long.

Comment: @ken_sfdc please click the "edit" link below your question and from there you can add the additional code so that we can assist you further.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put in system.debugs and check to the logs to see where the null value is coming in.  BarCotter was right when he said `taskParentMap`, but there are also other ones .

```
if((userProfileMap.get(taskOwnerMap.get(loopTask.Id)).toLowerCase()).contains('nam'))  

if((userProfileMap.get(taskOwnerMap.get(loopTask.Id)).toLowerCase()).contains('lsm'))

loopTask.Veeva_Service_Request_LookUp__c = loopTask.whatId;
            loopTask.whatId = vsrToSR.get(loopTask.whatId);
```

Pretty much wherever there is a `.get`   can cause that..

Are you sure there is something wrong with your query?   Put your query into force.com explorer or developer console and see if it returns anything.

Comment: see the debuglogs Yes I think query is wrong 10:29:34.183 (183364602)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[37]|Aggregations:0|select Id, Service_Request_Id__c from Veeva_Service_Request__c 
10:29:34.204 (204071837)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[37]|Rows:0

Comment: So then it goes back to what @BarCotter said..  `taskParentMap`  could be null

Comment: So how to change the query to only execute when it is not null.

Comment: First get the value from UserProfileMap in an object. String userProfile = userProfileMap.get(taskOwnerMap.get(loopTask.Id)); Then check if userProfile is not null. if(userProfile != null){ userProfile = userProfile.toLowerCase(); if(userProfile.contains(...);} etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the size >0 and then assign if(loopVSR.size() >0){}

Comment: Where can I add this if(loopVSR.size() >0){} which lineplease?

Comment: Hi Ken, In each for loop you need to check for the Null values.